# Visual Studio Community 2013 SP4 shows no colors in Text Editor, black & white only

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8, colors, 64-bit, text-editor

[image: VS 2013 Color Theme Selection]

Problem occurs if I log in as a standard user.
Tools | Options | Environment | General | ComboBox Color Theme: is grayed out

I tried:

- uncheck CheckBox "Automatically adjust visual experience ..."
- Tools | Import and Export Settings | Reset all settings
- Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors | Button "Use Default"
- devenv.exe /resetuserdata
- installing Extension "Visual Studio 2013 Color Theme Editor" (Tools | Color Theme: is grayed out)
- running Visual Studio with admin rights
- installing Visual Studio as admin user (current)
- installing Visual Studio as standard user (while antivirus is disabled)

Problem is gone and Visual Studio works as expected if I log in as admin user.
Expression Blend 12 Update 4 is working well, shows editor colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the windows theme color settings caused the issue. I moved to a windows built in theme.